# How to keep selection after changing DOM Element's text?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, selection, innerhtml

I have a countdown clock (days / hours / minutes / seconds) on my website, which looks like this:

[image: Countdown]

It works perfectly, except one thing that could be improved.

When the clock ticks, which is every second, it loses the selection. In other words, if someone wants to select and copy some of the block, it's virtually impossible, unless someone makes it under 1 second.

Is there any DOM method of changing the Node's text that won't make the browsers remove selection?

I tried these:

```
div.innerHTML = secondsLeft; // loses selection in both Chrome and Firefox
div.innerText = secondsLeft; // not W3C standard, loses selection in Firefox
div.textContent = secondsLeft; // loses selection in both Chrome and Firefox
div.firstChild.textContent = secondsLeft; // loses selection in Firefox
```